# How to find certain items in an xml?

Tags: xml, processing

I have an xml and all, and the good thing is, I can run it in processing. So when I press run, in the box in the bottom I get all the scores of all the teams. Why, here's the code:

```
XML xml;

void setup() {
  xml = loadXML("http://www.scorespro.com/rss2/live-basketball.xml");
  XML[] channel = xml.getChildren("channel");
   //println(xml);
  for (int i = 0; i < channel.length; i++) {
    String item = channel[i].getString("title");
    String name = channel[i].getContent();
    println(channel);
  }
}
```

Now I am wondering. I only want to get for example the Miami Heat's score. Is that possible?

Comment: As always, use **XPath**. What is the programming language anyway? You also shoud provide the XmlSchema since we can't derive the structure of the Xml file with this description...

Comment: @CommuSoft, looks like a Java

Comment: @CommuSoft and v2p: The language is Processing.

Comment: Crossposted: http://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/10282/finding-certain-points-in-an-xml-file

Comment: When I run the program I get a whole bunch of stuff, but the good thing is that I can see the teams that played, and the scores they got. Now, I don't want all the extra information. I only want to know one team and what they got. Only one.

Comment: So do that. Write some kind of loops through the teams, and only does something when you find the right team.

Comment: Hey Mike Pomaz Kamermans, the problem is I do not know how to do that. Do I use .getChildren() somehow?

Comment: @TechWiz777 What happened when you tried that?

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to use that function, at all!

Comment: @TechWiz777 and that's fine: read the documentation on the XML element over on the http://processing.org/reference site, and start trying things.

Answer (score 0):

Processing has a [built-in XML library](https://processing.org/reference/XML.html) that can do exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I can already use that. I just want Processing to print out a certain part of what the xml returns, not the whole string, that is too long.

Comment: See the comments on the Processing thread – this is *exactly* what the XML library does. If you want to chop part of the particular entry within the XML, your question is really about regular expressions and you should edit your question above.