# How to search through XML using Processing?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, processing

I am using the [Processing](https://processing.org/) language with XML. I found a similar question here: [How to find certain items in an xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29584567/how-to-find-certain-items-in-an-xml). But that question has not been answered yet. Anyways, I was wondering, when I got the result of the XML file, how do I search through it for a certain string? Do I search using the `.getChildren()` function? A lot of strings are returned, but I want to search for a certain string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [parseXML()](https://processing.org/reference/parseXML_.html) in [Processing](https://processing.org/) 2.0:

```
String data = "<mammals><animal>Goat</animal></mammals>";

void setup() {
  XML xml = parseXML(data);
  if (xml == null) {
    println("XML could not be parsed.");
  } else {
    XML firstChild = xml.getChild("animal");
    println(firstChild.getContent());
  }
}

// Sketch prints:
// Goat
```

See also the [Processing 2.0 XML](https://processing.org/reference/XML.html) examples and methods.

```
// The following short XML file called "mammals.xml" is parsed 
// in the code below. It must be in the project's "data" folder.
//
// <?xml version="1.0"?>
// <mammals>
//   <animal id="0" species="Capra hircus">Goat</animal>
//   <animal id="1" species="Panthera pardus">Leopard</animal>
//   <animal id="2" species="Equus zebra">Zebra</animal>
// </mammals>

XML xml;

void setup() {
  xml = loadXML("mammals.xml");
  XML[] children = xml.getChildren("animal");

  for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    int id = children[i].getInt("id");
    String coloring = children[i].getString("species");
    String name = children[i].getContent();
    println(id + ", " + coloring + ", " + name);
  }
}

// Sketch prints:
// 0, Capra hircus, Goat
// 1, Panthera pardus, Leopard
// 2, Equus zebra, Zebra
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that answer! I will try it out, and tell you what happened!

Comment: Okay, so the problem is when I run my code, this is what I get: so many things. See I don't actually have an xml file, this XML is a WEBSITE. So it keeps on updating and stuff. So when I run the code, it prints out the whole xml. Now I only want parts of that stuff. What could I do? Actually, I am using the same website as the other question: Check it out: http://www.scorespro.com/rss2/live-basketball.xml. @kjhughes

Comment: This is my code:                                                                        XML xml;
XML[] item;
XML[] channel;


void setup() {
  size(500,500);
  xml = loadXML("http://www.scorespro.com/rss2/live-basketball.xml");
  channel = xml.getChildren("channel");
  item = channel[0].getChildren("item");
  println(item);
  for (int i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
  }
}

Comment: Sorry about the formatting I don't know how to format it in a comment.

Comment: So I saved the xml as a file, so I'm still trying by the way.